# Show that a retract of a Hausdorff space is closed.

Tags: general-topology

#### Definitions:

> A subspace $A \subset X$ is called a retract of $X$ if there is a map $r: X \rightarrow A$ such that $r(a) = a$ for all $a \in A$. (Such a map is called a retraction.)

#### Problem statement:

> Show that a retract of a Hausdorff space is closed.

#### Proof:

*Proof.* Let $x \notin A$ and $a =r(x) \in A$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff, $x$ and $a$ have disjoint neighborhoods $U$ and $V$, respectively. Then $r^{−1}(V \cap A) \cap U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ disjoint from $A$. (*) Hence, $A$ is closed.

#### Question:

I do not understand how  "$r^{−1}(V \cap A) \cap U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ disjoint from $A$" implies that $A$ is closed. I would be grateful if someone could point me in te right direction.

Comment: Actually, I think it is more natural to prove this by noting that $A$ is the set of fixed points of $r$.

Comment: And the set of fixed points of $r$ is necessarily closed in $X$?

Comment: Yes. The set of fixed points is the inverse image of the diagonal in $X\times X$ under the continuous map $x\mapsto(x,r(x))$, and the diagonal is itself closed. (There are more direct proofs too, none of them really difficult.)

Comment: Does anyone except me has the trouble understanding why $r^{-1}(V\cap A)$ is open in the first place?

Comment: @mathreader: Since the image of $r$ is (contained in) $A$ already, $r^{-1}(V\cap A)=r^{-1}(V)$.

Comment: How does $V \cap A = V$? If $V$ is just an open neighborhood of $r(x)$ then how can you be sure that there aren't points in $V$ that are in $X$ \ $A$?

Comment: @OliverG I don't think $V \cap A=V$ is implied. Clearly, $LHS \subseteq RHS$. Conversely, $x \in RHS \Rightarrow r(x) \in V$. But the image of $r$ is in $A$, so $r(x) \in V \cap A$ and $x \in r^{-1}(V \cap A)$.

Comment: The set $V \cap A$ is an open set in the subspace topology for $A$. Since $r : X \to A$ is continuous, that implies that the inverse image is open.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The proof shows that the complement of $A$ is open.

Comment: Why is it true that $r^{−1}(V \cap A) \cap U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ disjoint from $A$, though? How do we know we can find a neighborhood U disjoint from A?

Comment: @Ryker It is true because if $x$ belongs to that set, by definition $x\in U$ and $r(x)\in V$. Therefore $r(x)\ne x$, so $x\notin A$.

Comment: Thanks! I actually managed to figure it out on my own in the meantime, but I figured I'd leave the question, so that if you answered someone else might find it useful, as well.

Comment: You should use another variable. Since a person may confuse the $x$ you used for the arguement, and $x$ used in the main arguement of the question @HaraldHanche-Olsen

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom You have a point there, but I can't edit such an old comment. In any case, the reader coming here will be able to see your notice and take corrective action.

Answer (score 3):

Why $r^{-1}(V\cap A)\cap U$ is disjoint from $A$?

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
y\in r^{-1}(V\cap A)\cap U & \Leftrightarrow & y\in\{ z\in X: r(z)\in V\cap A \}\cap U \\
& \Leftrightarrow & y\in\{ z\in U: r(z)\in V\cap A \}.
\end{array}
$$
So $y\notin A$. If the opposite was true $\;$($y\in A$)$\;$ it should be $y\in U \Rightarrow r(y)\in U$, $\;$but $r(y)\in V\cap A\subset V$ and $U\cap V=\varnothing$.