# An embedding that is a closed map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, closed-map

> Suppose $f:A \rightarrow B$, $g:B \rightarrow A$, such that $gf=1_A$. If $B$ is Hausdorff, then $f$ is a closed map.

Any hints would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is an embedding because it has a left inverse. Hence w.l.o.g. we may assume that $A \subset B$ and $f$ is the inclusion. This means that $A$ is a retract of $B$. To show that a retract of a Hausdorff space is closed has been several times asked and answered in this forum, e.g.

[Why does this argument show that a retract of a Hausdorff space is closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/382971)

[Show that a retract of a Hausdorff space is closed.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/278755)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Use the characterization of closedness with nets : if $F$ is closed and $(f(y_i))$ is a converging net in $B$, what can you say about $(y_i)$ ?

> Let $F$ be closed in $A$; $(x_i)$ a converging net in $f(F)$, call $x$ its limit. Write $x_i = f(y_i)$ for some $y_i\in F$. Then $x_i \to x$ implies $g(x_i)\to g(x)$ but $g(x_i)= y_i$ so $y_i\to g(x)$. Note that $g(x) \in F$ because $F$ is closed and $y_i \in F$. Thus $f(y_i)\to f(g(x))$; $x_i\to f(g(x))$. But $B$ is Hausdorff, so $(x_i)$ has at most one limit: $x=f(g(x))$. In particular, $x\in f(F)$. Any converging net in $f(F)$ has its limit in $f(F)$: thus $f(F)$ is closed; and so $f$ is closed.

Comment: But what happen if g is not continuous?

Comment: @ChristianCoronel : I took it as implicit that $g$ (and $f$) were assumed to be continuous; otherwise the result is wrong - indeed, it suffices for $f$ to be injective (and $A$ nonempty) for a noncontinuous $g$ to exist, while the existence of a continuous $g$ is a real restriction

Comment: I have to proof this, but only can assume that f is continuous

Comment: @ChristianCoronel : as I said, if $g$ is not assumed to be continuous, the result is wrong :) So I hope you don't have to prove it ! :D

Answer (score 1):

There is a more general statement. Let  $h,k: A \to B$  be continuous functions. If $B$ is Hausdorff, the the set $C_{h,k}=\{a \in A: h(a)=k(a) \} $ is closed in $A$.

**Proof** We know that $B$ is Hausdorff if and only if the diagonal $\Delta_B$, i.e. the set of elements $(b,b)\in B \times B: b \in B$ is closed in $B \times B$.
 But $C_{h,k}= (h,k)^{-1}(\Delta_B). $ QED

For the question  at issue, we look at $h=fg, k=1: B \to B$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $f, g$ are continuous. Let $b$  be an element of the closure of $f(A)$.  Since $B$ is Hausdorff, we have  $b= lim_nf(a_n)$. Since $g$ and $f$ are continous, $lim_ng(f(a_n))=a_n =g(b) $ and  $lim_nf(a_n) =f(g(b)) =b$. Since a limit is unique in an Hausdorff space.

Comment: Note that you can't use the sequential criterion with usual sequences $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}$ because you have no metrizability or countability hypothesis on the spaces