# Retracts and Closed Subspaces in Discrete Spaces

Tags: general-topology, retraction

Prove that any closed subspace of the space  = $^{ℵ0}$,
where  is a discrete space
of any power, is a retract of the space .

I think we can try to reduce the problem to this: [Show that a retract of a Hausdorff space is closed.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/278755/1255520).

But how can we neatly write that we can consider B as Hausdorff and solve the inverse problem: if there it follows from the fact that A is retracted that A is closed, then here it follows from the fact that A is closed that A is retracted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.